# count the multiple column values in hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

below is the data set for a household member ( eight-member) by there type.....

```
h1      h2      h3      h4      h5      h6      h7      h8
U       U       P       U       Y       null    Y       U
U       H       U       U       Y       Y       P       P
U       U       U       H       U       nuLL    Y       null
null    null    H       H       U       null    null    null
P       U       U       U       Y       null    Z       P
Y       P       null    H       Y       P       U       H
U       null    U       null    P       U       Z       Y
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
```

in the above data set to count the total number of H= head of household,P= parent of household,U=adult, Y= wife of household, null= No match.  i used this code and this code giving me the right count of household member by type but i case of null i am not getting proper count. can any one tell me why that is happening? please resolve it. below i am providing my code

```
select sum( Head_cnt) as H,
       sum( parent_cnt) as P,
       sum( adult_cnt) as U,
       sum(spouce_cnt) as Y,
       sum( nomatch_cnt) as Nomatch 
from(
select length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^U]', '')) as adult_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^H]', '')) as head_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^P]', '')) as parent_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^Y]', '')) as spouce_cnt, 
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[null]', '')) as nomatch_cnt
from(select concat_ws(',',h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8) as row_concatenated 
       from table_name)s
)s;
```

please give me the solution for it ......for null value in the code. i am getting proper count for all the values except the null value. and just remember this is not an NULL value. here null mean NO MATCH.

Comment: please give me a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to count the occurrences of each letter in each column ignoring NULL. One way to do it is to union all columns then group by and count:

```
with union_table as (
  select h1 as h
  union all 
  select h2 as h
  union all 
  ... (up to h8)
  select h8 as h
    from your_table
)
select h, count(*) as cnt
  from union_table
 group by h
```

The default `count` function will ignore NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Convert null values to some character, say 'N' for No match:

```
select sum( Head_cnt) as H,
       sum( parent_cnt) as P,
       sum( adult_cnt) as U,
       sum(spouce_cnt) as Y,
       sum( nomatch_cnt) as Nomatch 
from(
select length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^U]', '')) as adult_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^H]', '')) as head_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^P]', '')) as parent_cnt,
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^Y]', '')) as spouce_cnt, 
length(regexp_replace(row_concatenated, '[^N]', '')) as nomatch_cnt
from
    (
     select concat_ws(',',nvl(h1,'N'),nvl(h2,'N'),nvl(h3,'N'),nvl(h4,'N'),nvl(h5,'N'),nvl(h6,'N'),nvl(h7,'N'),nvl(h8,'N')) as row_concatenated 
       from table_name)s
)s;
```

Comment: no i cant replace null with N because i need to maintain that as per instruction. so there any other solution is possible?

Comment: @SaikatRoy  I did it like  per your instruction.. calculated nulls as nomatch. Please explain why do you think it is not what you are expecting